# Where do I put constructor parameters when creating an instance of a class inside a class?

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to make my `Class2` have an instance of `Class1` put I don't know where to put my constructor parameters. I have the following code:

```
class Class1 {
public:    Class1(std::string name) { myName = name; }
private:   std::string myName;
};

class Class2  {
private:
    Class1 player("Steve"); 
};
```

Produces the error:

> ```
> prog.cpp:12:20: error: expected identifier before string constant
>
>  Class1 player("Steve");
>
>                ^~~~~~~
> prog.cpp:12:20: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before string constant
> ```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/ILu7m2)

**How can i construct my class correctly?**

Comment: [*Member initializer list* or *default member initializer*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization).

Comment: Have you read any documentation? I would start here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: `gets me an error` is not descriptive enough. What does the error say?

Comment: I have fixed your question. Remember in future, you need a minimal complete example and the exact information about the error you are receiving. You are getting free help. Make it easy for us to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Class1 player` is a member variable of `Class2`. `Class1` has no default constructor because you declared one taking a `string`. Therefore your only option is the initializer list of `Class2`s constructor:

```
class Class2 {
    public: Class2() : player("Steve") {} // Initializer list 
    private: Class1 player;
};
```

Or if you have c++11 using the default member initializer:

```
class Class2 { 
    private: Class1 player{"Steve"};
};
```

Information on both can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members). A live example can be found [here](https://ideone.com/KGLA4d).

Comment: or the inline initialization (since c++14 i believe)

Comment: @user463035818 Yeah i forgot about that, still stuck in 03 :(

Comment: and I already started to feel cool because I am soo oldschool c++11 :P

Comment: @user463035818 Yeah, the embedded industry moves slowly. Ultra slowly. We managed to upgrade 1 os that we run on to c++11, but we have communicating devices, so a bunch of shared code (most of the code) still has to run on 03 XD